# Why does BitmapImage RequestCachePolicy get ignored?

Tags: wpf, httpwebrequest, bitmapimage

I'm finding that setting the `RequestCachePolicy` property on `BitmapImage` has no effect on how the bitmap is downloaded when an `Image`'s `Source` is set to this instance of `BitmapImage`.

For example, if I set the `RequestCachePolicy` to `CacheOnly`, I would expect no internet traffic to occur whatsoever - the specified image should only be retrieved from the cache. But instead, I see a request being made to the server to download an image:

```
source = new BitmapImage(bmi.UriSource, 
  new RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.CacheOnly));
// An image gets downloaded!
```

If I set the static `DefaultCachePolicy` property on `HttpWebRequest`, then my application behaviour changes in a way I would expect. ie when it's set to `CacheOnly`, no network traffic occurs.

Why is the `RequestCachePolicy` property on `BitmapImage` not having the effect I expect?

Answer (score 1):

According to the MSDN site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cache.requestcachepolicy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

> *"Caching for Web services is not supported."*